# Displaying a view fails

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

On a page I insert a button that will direct the user to another view (newview.ctp)

in the controller I create a function

```
function newview()
{ 
   if($this->Session->read($this->_userName))
   {
      $this->loadSkinForAction();
      $user = $this->user->findByUsername($this->Session->read('User'));
      $this->set('item',$user);
   }
}
```

In the page as I mention I simply insert a button this way

```
<input type="button" value="Change Your self" onclick="window.location.assign('../users/newview')" />
```

The view newview.ctp looks something like this

```
<?php
if(isset($item))
{
    echo $form->create(null,array('url' => '/users/newview/'.$item['User']['id']));
}
?>
<h1>Change your password</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>New password</td>
        <td><?php $form->password('password',$newPassword);?></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Confirm password</td>
        <td><?php echo $form->password('password_',$newPasswordConfirm);?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $form->end('Save');
}?>
```

When i click the button in the page, it doesn't show the new page but a blank page instead,

Comment: doesnt the function in controller supposed to "return" $item ?

Comment: Chk is the path "../users/newview" in onClick attribute valid as per ur directory structure?, please add Firebug in ur FF browser and debug

Comment: Just to clarify, a blank page usually indicates that a fatal error has occurred and your debug level in CakePHP is set to 0. If you open your /app/config/core.php file and set the debug level to 1 or 2 you will hopefully get an error message which will help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you David you helped me spot the error exactly. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Does the page which links to the "newview()" page need to be a HTML button? Or simply a link?

If it is a link, use CakePHP's Html helper functions. [Link](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1435/Inserting-Well-Formatted-elements#link-1442)

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Change Password', '/users/newview'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand any difference that has with an html button?

Comment: A HTML button is part of a <form>. If you are simply wanting to redirect the user to a new page, use a link (which I posted above).

Comment: But addint that link fails the whole current page. I will update my OP to clearify how the current page is made and processed